# Scatter Plot of a Specific Column in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, but I am determined to learn how to use it. At the moment, I am working with .dat files that have a few columns only separated by spaces.

I was wondering if there is anyway that I can make a scatter plot with a specific column accompanied by each value's non-negative integer? (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4...).

Here is an example of the data I am working with:

[image: data screenshot]

[Here is an example graph of what I would want to be the end result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6haI.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "each value's non-negative integer"? Do you mean the row number, starting with zero for the first data row? If so, a line graph would be more appropriate than a scatter plot, which is meant to show the relationship between two variables. Also, how is the data input--as a text file as shown, as a dataset, a list of lists, a numpy array, or other? Please give more detail--a sample graph resulting from your example would help, even if it is very crude.

Comment: `plt.scatter(x, y, c=color)` to make a scatterplot of the arrays `x`, `y` and `color`, see [the matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html). `color` contains the values that define the color of the points. Column `n` is accessed with `data[:, n]`.

Comment: You may want to look into [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is made for this sort of thing.